# Centralizer of $A_m$ in $A_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Problem: I want to
calculate centralizer of $A_m$ in $A_n$. As far as I
   know, $A_{i},\ i\geq 5$ is simple. So if $m\geq 5$, then $$ C
   := \{ a\in A_n|\ ax=xa\ \forall x\in A_m\} = A_{n-m} $$

Proof: Clearly $C\supseteq A_{n-m}$ : Assume
that $A_n$ permutes $\{1,\ \cdots,\ n\}$, $A_m$ permutes $X:=\{ 1,\ \cdots,\ m\}$ and $A_{n-m}$
permutes $Y:=\{ m+1,\ \cdots,\ n\} $.

(1) $A_m$ is simple so that there exists no nontrivial
center.

(2) If $\tau\in C-A_{n-m}$, then $\tau(a)=b,\ a\in X,\ b\in Y$. For convenience by rearranging, we can let $a=1,\ b=m+1$. Consider $
\alpha =(123)\in A_m$. That is, $\alpha (1)=2 \in X$. By definition of
$\tau$ we have $\tau^{-1}\alpha \tau=\alpha $. But $$ 2=
\alpha(1)=\tau^{-1}\alpha\tau (1)=\tau^{-1}\alpha(m+1)=\tau^{-1}
(m+1)=1 $$ It is a contradiction. So $C=A_{n-m}$. So we complete the
proof.

Am I correct ?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are doing in part (3). Assuming that part (2) was about explaining why $A_{n-m}$ centralizes $A_m$. By that logic you should be trying to show that nothing out side of $A_{n-m}$ centralizes all of $A_m$.

Comment: And there is nothing wrong with the inequation about dimensions. Why should there be an equality there?

Comment: I see. I fix it.

Comment: I'm still clueless about your part (3). Shouldn't you take an arbitrary element $a\notin A_{n-m}$ and then produce a $x\in A_m$ such that $ax\neq xa$? Your $\sigma\notin A_m$?

Comment: Well I will edit more clearly

Comment: Much better now, but I think that at this level you should be more specific about how you find the required $a$ and $b$, or why they exist. Also be more specific about what the contradiction actually is :-)

Comment: You are right. I edit again